# ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' Unsupported config option for services.web: 'dockerfile'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an error when I try to build :

```
$ docker-compose build
```

> ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
>   Unsupported config option for services.web: 'dockerfile'

Here's the content of my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
#docker-compose.yml

version: '2'
services:
 db:
   image: mysql
   environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=db
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd
   volumes:
    - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
 web:
   build: .
   dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
   entrypoint: ./script.sh db:3306 --
   command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
   environment:
     - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=db.docker_settings
     - CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER=True
   volumes:
     - .:/code
     - /code/node_modules/
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
   depends_on:
     - db
```

I tried looking here : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/
but couldn't find any solution.

Any clue on this ? I'm still a beginner with docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.` after `build:`. Also, fix your indentation, like this:

```
   build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
   entrypoint: ./script.sh db:3306 --
...
```

Comment: Ok thank you kenny_k. That was it. In fact I had another error after that. It was a context issue. I needed to  add `context: .` right after the build line. Maybe you can add it to you answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

there's a problem with your indentation in docker-compose.yaml, make following changes

```
web:
   build: 
     dockerfile: dev.Dockerfile
   entrypoint: ./script.sh db:3306 --
   command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Thank you @mohammed it was this. I marked kenny_k right answer as he answered first, but thank you again!